# streamreader not getting proper count of lines

Tags: c#, file, line, readfile, streamreader

It counts 23 but there are 30 lines that are "Placeholder:Placeholder"............................................................................

```
      using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(File.Open(AccountsFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)))
            {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = Reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (line == "Placeholder:Placeholder")
                        {
                            int count = line.Count();  
                        }
                    }
            }
```

Comment: Since it is only 30 lines, can you add the entire text file to your question? By the way, `line.Count()` doesn't do what you think it does if you are trying to count lines in a text file. Here's a hint: `Placeholder:Placeholder` has 23 characters.

Comment: line.Count() returns the number of characters in line variable. So it returns 23 because "Placeholder:Placeholder" has 23 characters.

Comment: @Han oh thanks, but how do I get the line count of all the lines that have "Placeholder:Placeholder" in them? I tried doing File.ReadLines().Count() method under the if statement but it gives me the total line count in the file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable to store the count and increment it every time a line matches a pattern string.

```
using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(File.Open(AccountsFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)))
{
    string line;
    int count = 0;
    while ((line = Reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line == "Placeholder:Placeholder")
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh thanks lol, was that simple. Sorry to waste your time just half a sleep right now.